# File downloaded is different from what is on server

Tags: javascript, csv, flask, download

I have a flask app. This front end of which has a "download button" to download a file.
This is how I am triggering a download:

```
$('#download_file').attr('onClick',"window.open('data.csv')");
```

I am facing a critical issue.
data.csv is like this:

```
            Jan-15  Feb-15  Mar-15
Strike Rate 97.00   90.00   95.00
```

Jan-15 is 1/1/2015

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6rwN.png)

But when I download from front end:
Data.csv

```
            15-Jan  15-Feb  15-Mar
Strike Rate 97.00   90.00   95.00
```

here first column is 15-Jan (i.e 15 Jan 2020), 15-Feb (15 Feb 2020)…..

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdXNH.png)

Where is this data.csv getting changed?

Comment: have you check the csv in a text editor not in excel?

Comment: Yes, I did that, on notepad I can see 1-Jan-15,1-Feb-15,1-Mar-15 for original csv. But, for the same csv downloaded I see Jan-15, Feb-15, Mar-15