# Any way to stop auto reformatting of data in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am asking a follow up question from here ([File downloaded is different from what is on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687051/file-downloaded-is-different-from-what-is-on-server)).

I have datetime in csv file which is getting reformatted.

My CSV has data like this 1-Jan-15,1-Feb-15,1-Mar-15.
But, the reformated csv is like Jan-15, Feb-15, Mar-15.......

Is there any way to stop automatic reformatting of data?

Comment: An Excel date is actually a floating point number. How it displays a date as year, month and day is purely a formatting issue. Is the date displayed on the formula bar (not in the body of the spreadsheet) what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the .csv file directly in Excel, open a new blank workbook in Excel and use `Get Data from Text` (under the `Data` tab of the Ribbon) to import the .csv file.

This will open the `Text Import Wizard`, which has 3 total screens.

- On Step 1, choose `Delimited`.
- On Step 2, choose `Comma`.
- And on Step 3, highlight all columns with dates in them and choose `Text`.

Click `Finish`.

The `General` format (which is also what happens by default if you open a .csv file in Excel directly) will recognize the dates as being dates and reformat them according to your locale settings. By instructing Excel to interpret those columns as text, they will not be recognized as dates and therefore left as they are.